# SQL Server 2012 window function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table which holds status of jobs in a history table.

#### JobHistory

```
jobOrderId | dateAdded               | Status
-----------|-------------------------|-------
4909       | 2015-08-26 18:15:07.527 | OPEN
4909       | 2015-08-28 13:35:38.997 | CLOSE
4909       | 2015-08-31 12:16:29.787 | OPEN
4910       | 2015-08-27 12:16:42.72  | OPEN
4910       | 2015-08-28 17:04:43.617 | CLOSE
4910       | 2015-08-31 17:01:27.337 | OPEN
4911       | 2015-08-27 16:08:39.467 | OPEN
```

I would like to get the following output

```
jobOrderId | opendate   | closedate
-----------|------------|-----------
4909       | 2015-08-26 | 2015-08-28
4909       | 2015-08-31 | NULL
4910       | 2015-08-27 | 2015-08-28
4910       | 2015-08-31 | NULL
4911       | 2015-08-27 | NULL
```

Can any one suggest me how to get this kind of output using SQL Server 2012 window functions?

Comment: How complicated are the scenarios?  What if 4909 had OPEN/OPEN/OPEN/CLOSE/OPEN/CLOSE/CLOSE ?

Comment: @GordonLinoff My guess is a job only can be `open` if is `close` or not exist. So can't have open/open

Comment: Yes it's a pairs. Either Open/Close this can appear as many times. The last one can be left open. There can never be Open/Open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.jobOrderId
       , CONVERT(DATE,dateAdded) [OpenDate]
       ,(SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(DATE,dateAdded)
         FROM TableName 
         WHERE jobOrderId = t.jobOrderId
          AND  dateAdded > t.dateAdded
          AND  [Status] = 'CLOSE'
         ORDER BY dateAdded ASC) AS [CloseDate]
FROM TableName t
WHERE t.[Status] = 'OPEN'
```

### OR

```
SELECT t.jobOrderId
       , CONVERT(DATE,dateAdded) [OpenDate]
       ,C.CloseDate
FROM TableName t
  OUTER APPLY (  SELECT TOP 1 CONVERT(DATE,dateAdded)
                 FROM TableName 
                 WHERE jobOrderId = t.jobOrderId
                  AND  dateAdded > t.dateAdded
                  AND  [Status] = 'CLOSE'
                 ORDER BY dateAdded ASC) c ([CloseDate])
WHERE t.[Status] = 'OPEN'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example.

*NOTE* i have not forgotten to add a where for closed, in my function. Its simply not needed as based on the rules Ie OPEN -> CLOSED you would always find a closed after an open or nothing at all. So you don't need to check for the status.   If there was a second open after the open then you could change the code or correct your data.

```
DECLARE @Data TABLE(jobOrderId INT,dateAdded DATETIME,Status NVARCHAR(8))
INSERT INTO @Data
VALUES
(4909,'2015-08-26 18:15:07.527','OPEN'),
(4909,'2015-08-28 13:35:38.997','CLOSE'),
(4909,'2015-08-31 12:16:29.787','OPEN'),
(4910,'2015-08-27 12:16:42.72','OPEN'),
(4910,'2015-08-28 17:04:43.617','CLOSE'),
(4910,'2015-08-31 17:01:27.337','OPEN'),
(4911,'2015-08-27 16:08:39.467','OPEN')

SELECT      jobOrderId,CAST(dateAdded AS DATE),(SELECT CAST(MIN(dateAdded) AS DATE) FROM @Data AS DB WHERE DA.dateAdded < DB.dateAdded AND DA.jobOrderId = DB.jobOrderId)
FROM        @Data AS DA
WHERE       Status = 'OPEN'
```